# wkhtmltoPDF KnpSnappyBundle Error The exit status code '127' says something went wrong: stderr: "sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I have a problem with the path of my wkhtmltopdf which does not find it a priori. Do you have the beginning of a solution ?

knp_snappy.yaml

```
knp_snappy:
pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     '%env(WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH)%'
    options:    []
image:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     '%env(WKHTMLTOIMAGE_PATH)%'
    options:    []
```

.env

```
    ###> knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle ###
WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH=/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
WKHTMLTOIMAGE_PATH=/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
###< knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle ###
```

Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/pdf-snappy", name="generate_pdf")
 */
public function snappy(PDF $pdf,UserActivityRepository $userActivityRepository, TestimonyViewRepository $testimonyViewRepository)
{

    $html = $this->renderView('Modules/PDF/test.html.twig');
    
    $pdf->setOption('page-size','A4');
    $pdf->setOption('orientation', 'Landscape');

    return new Response(
        $pdf->getOutputFromHtml($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition'   => 'inline; filename="' . 'test' . '.pdf"'
        )
    );


}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi. Can you add /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf directly on your knp_snappy.yaml? Just to see if the problem is wkhtmltopdf or your .env config.

Comment: I placed in the knp_snappy.yaml '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf' and the error remains the same